# Is there a faster alternative to sympy to compute intersection of 3D segments and planes?

Tags: python, performance, geometry, sympy, intersection

I am writing a  Python code that needs to analyze if thousands of segments intersect with a cube. My approach has been to use SYMPY to compute the intersection between each segment and each face of the cube.
This is painfully slow, and I need something that is at least one order of magnitude faster. Any alternative library or approach?
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The idea with using sympy for something like this would be that you use it to derive the equations that you can then implement numerically.